# Correct way to expose instance variables to other classes

Tags: java

Can someone help me understand this:

"For example, an object's instance variables (member fields that aren't constants), should always be private. Period. No exceptions. Ever. I mean it. (You can occasionally use protected methods effectively, but protected instance variables are an abomination.) You should never use get/set functions for the same reason—they're just overly complicated ways to make a field public (though access functions that return full-blown objects rather than a basic-type value are reasonable in situations where the returned object's class is a key abstraction in the design)." - http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073649/core-java/why-extends-is-evil.html

I don't understand what he means by, "You should never use get/set functions for the same reason—they're just overly complicated ways to make a field public."  Let's say I have a simple Person class with Name and Age instance variables.  How should I make these available to other classes?  Does he mean that I should create a Data Transfer Object?  Would this be a correct implementation?  Is this really preferable to having the getters and setters in the Person class?

```
public class Person {
    private PersonData personData;

    public Person (String name, int age){
        this.personData = 
            new PersonData(name, age);
    }

    // get personData

    // person methods...
}

// data transfer object
class PersonData {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    public PersonData(String name, int age){
        this.setName(name);
        this.setAge(age);
    }
    // getters and setters ...
}
```

Comment: The author has its own view of what Java code should look like, and his views aren't shared by many people in the Java world. They're also impossible to follow in many situations, because frameworks rely on principles and conventions that violate Holub's views. I would take that article only as an opinion, and not follow it blindly. What I agree with, though, is that you shouldn't automatically add getters, and even less setters, for every instance variable you have. They should be added wisely, when they make sense and don't break encapsulation.

Comment: See [When are Getters and Setters Justified](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/when-are-getters-and-setters-justified) for much discussion on this very topic

Comment: First off, the guy is wrong.  It's a nice approach when you have classes that need to be kept at an arm's length, but if you have several classes that are "intimate" with each other (eg, a hashtable class and the hashtable entry class within it) then allowing one class to access the other's instance vars directly can often be justified.  And the whole tirade about `inherits` is wrong too.  (And, yes, I know Allen Holub is a god, but some gods don't deserve to be worshiped quite so much.)

Comment: (And whether or not Holub has a point to a degree, it's not something you should worry about until you become reasonably proficient in the language.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a comment that an answer...

The article is dedicated to stablishing the need/advantages of *loose coupling*, and techniques to get it.

One of the points is avoiding relying in the internal data structure of an object, and only use its operators. In that point, automatically making your state accessible is bad, since objects using your classes may rely in these properties instead of using the more "refined" operations given to them.

From my understanding of the article, a possible example could be the following:

Imagine a `Person` class/interface with two operations, say, `isOldEnoughToBuyBeer` and `isOldEnoughToDriveCars`.

if you create in `Person` a setter/getter for `dateOfBirth`, then you are tying the implementations of `Person` to have such a property, and to implement the operations as "check current date agains `dateOfBirth` property and return true based in the number of years".

Of course, the statement "You should never use get/set functions for the same reason—they're just overly complicated ways to make a field public" may be too restrictive; while it is making a good point that even access through getters/setters has its consequences, it is hard to imagine that attributes are used only internally to the class that holds them.

Comment: Good answer, but if by *"it is hard to imagine that attributes are used only internally to the class that holds them."* you mean that `private` fields without `public` getters and setters are rare, then allow me to disagree. Good OOP design is about hiding implementation details (the private parts). If every attribute is exposed (by being `public` or having `public` get/setters), then the class is nothing more than a `struct`. I know that JavaBeans demand get/setters, but if you program (your domain) using POJOs (see DDD), having getters/setters/public fields is seldom a desirable goal.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely have getters for all the properties of the object you wish to expose to other objects. And if your object is mutable, you'll probably want setter methods for all the properties that can be modified.

set/get methods are **not** `overly complicated ways to make a field public`. They allow you to control the access and modification of your members.

For example, if your class is immutable, a get method that returns some object would return a clone of that object, to prevent the caller from modifing it.

For another example, if your class is mutable, a setter can contain validation of the new value you are trying to set.

Answer (score 0):

The author argues that you should never have public instance variables. *(Because they break encapsulation, but I believe you are not quiestioning this - if needed, though, we can get to it.)*

When he says ***"You should never use get/set functions for the same reason"*** he's saying that, in practice, having public `get` and `set` methods for an instance variable is roughly`*` the same as having the varible itself `public`.

The only difference (and the reason why he writes "they're just overly complicated ways to make a field public"), is that instead of the modifier `public` in the instance variable, you created two additional methods.

(Data) Transfer Objects are a complete different animal, they aren't related to the discussed context.

`*` "Roughly" because we are talking about the (usual) hipothesis of the getter and setter just reading and writing to the instance variable, not doing any additional processing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Correct way to expose instance variables to other classes
```

You should provide as low access to instance field as possible. The preferred way to provide access is to have three items

1. A private field
2. An public accessor method
3. An public mutator method

This Approach has following benefits

**First benefit:** This approach increases abstraction.

Suppose the getter(or accessor) method for Name is defined as follows

```
String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Now for some reason you want to change implementation of name as

```
String firstName;
String lastName;
```

In this case you can change `getName()` as

```
String getName() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Using this approach does not break your existing code which otherwise would be difficult(if not impossible) to obtain.

**Second benefit:** You can perform error checking all at once.

Consider a situation when the age entered by user is negative or practically impossible (like 99999999). In that case you can check such input in mutator method. This avoid manual checking and repetition of error check at different places

**In addition** it is advised that you should not write accessor method that return references to mutable object. This will break encapsulation. Use `.clone()` method of object class to return an object.